# AWS Glue custom grok classifier not working

Tags: logstash-grok, aws-glue

I have a structured delimited text file, with two columns, with **colons** as delimiters, in S3, which looks like this:

```
joe@gmail.com:abc
mary@yahoo.com:def
```

I have a custom classifier with this grok expression:
%{NOTSPACE:email}:%{NOTSPACE:data}

This expression works in grok expression tester here: https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/

But when I run this in my crawler, the table is created but it has an empty schema and no data.  Any suggestions?  Thanks.

Comment: Do you have all rows in one line?

Answer (score 0):

Had to use %{DATA:email}:%{WORD:data}

Comment: do you know why? I face the same problem: the pattern is valid at testers but aws glue is ignoring it